# WITH behavior - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, with-statement

This question is maybe noobish but i have not found direct answer for it.

How does with behave?

If i have

```
WITH tmp AS (...)
```

and then i use tmp 2 times in single query will tmp behave like macro in C or will it finish first time and rest in cache for next usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html) Says

> A useful property of WITH queries is that they are evaluated only once
>   per execution of the parent query, even if they are referred to more
>   than once by the parent query or sibling WITH queries. Thus, expensive
>   calculations that are needed in multiple places can be placed within a
>   WITH query to avoid redundant work

Comment: thank you so much. I completely missed that last paragraph, it is completely mu fault.